# External SSD shuts down midway through startup up then crashes. Mini then boots from internal drive

Tags: startup, ssd

Prior to today this external SSD boot has been functioning for 10 months. I’ve run Disk utility First Aid with clean results.

Suggestions?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: How do I get the startup to complete  and operate the external ssd T7 and not the mac mini hard drive? The system preferences are set to start with the T7. The start is initiated with the external ssd and opens os 12.7.1 but prior to completion it then quits to re start with the hard drive.

Comment: That *could* point to a failing external SSD or its enclosure. It could also point to anything else plugged into your Mac mini. It would be helpful to know the OS version and make/model of all involved hardware. Please edit your question and add that info